# Evaluate $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^3-x^2y}{\sqrt x+\sqrt y}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^3-x^2y}{\sqrt x+\sqrt y}$

I tried computing the limit along the x and y axis, also along the line $y=x$, and got that it all was 0.

So I think the limit actually evaluates to 0 but I'm having trouble proving this.

I don't know what I can factor? I tried applying to conjugate of $\sqrt x+\sqrt y$ but this just made it more complicated. How can I solve this limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^3-x^2y}{\sqrt x+\sqrt y}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}x^2\cdot\frac{x-y}{\sqrt x+\sqrt y}$$
$$=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}x^2(\sqrt x-\sqrt y)=0^2(\sqrt0-\sqrt0)=0$$

Comment: What happened to the $(x-y)$?

Comment: @VeeshaDawg $x-y=(\sqrt x+\sqrt y)(\sqrt x-\sqrt y)$. The difference of two squares. I know, it's a devilish trick, but it's needed here.

Comment: Oh wow that wasn't very obvious . Thank you

Comment: In 7minutes time I will

Comment: @VeeshaDawg You forgot?

Comment: Accepted now :)